# Apache server starts automatically. How to disable it?

Tags: apache2

Apache server starts automatically on my local machine on system startup. How can I disable it?

Comment: `systemctl stop apache2.service` and `systemctl disable apache2.service`

Comment: @FedonKadifeli why don't you post is as an answer so that requester can set it as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop auto restarting of the service at the time of system restart you need to run

`sudo systemctl disable service`

In your case it will be

`sudo systemctl disable apache2`

If your user have sudo previledges and it is in sudo group you can remove the sudo part from the command. If not then system will ask you for password of the system.

Answer (score 4):

Normally Apache server is not installed by default with Ubuntu. However, if it was installed somehow and you decided that you no longer need Apache server, you can completely remove it from the system using:

```
sudo apt purge apache2
```

If you need to temporarily disable Apache (without deleting it from the system), you can use:

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2.service
sudo systemctl disable apache2.service
```

So that later, if you decide to re-enable it, you can run:

```
sudo systemctl enable apache2.service
sudo systemctl start apache2.service
```

Information about the current run status of the Apache server can be obtained by:

```
systemctl status apache2.service
```